what is the difference between scope and group in LaTeX?
I try to figure out what is the difference, but it seems the same concept.
Because each is delimit in curly braces to appoint the command valid.

You may also have a look at this tag https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/grouping/info and that one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/scoping/info (which certainly needs some improvement) .

scope is not a defined term in tex, but it has standard english meaning as a range in which something applies, so it is occasionally used while describing the effect of a group. In the base latex format dtx source,  scope appears  28 times and group appears  1709 times.

@DavidCarlisle  what is standard english? :)

A group is something defined in the TeX language which underpins LaTex, a scope is normally a grouping level used in PGF/TikZ.
